# Javascript SyntaxError: missing ) after condition

Tags: javascript

Hi im working on the gaming website so when im erroring out the code i found this error. Could you help me her is the code:

```
this.collision = collision;
function collision(object) {
    if(this.x < object.x + 64 && this.x + this.16 > object.x) {
        if(this.y < object.y + 64 && this.y + 64 > object.y) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    } else return false;
}
```

Comment: `this.16` is one of your mistakes.

Comment: @Holt, not one of mistake but that's THE mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got `this.16` in your code, which doesn't work. What does execute correctly for me is simply removing `this` from that expression:

```
this.collision = collision;
function collision(object) {
    if(this.x < object.x + 64 && this.x + 16 > object.x) {
        if(this.y < object.y + 64 && this.y + 64 > object.y) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    } else return false;
}
```

But this might not be the same problem as the one you're having, since the error I received was `SyntaxError: Unexpected number`, not `SyntaxError: missing ) after condition`. This does execute correctly though, so this probably solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need those `else` statements. You should just be able to do this (assuming you fix the mistake that Holt mentions):

```
function collision(object) {
  if (this.x < object.x + 64 && this.x + this.16 > object.x) {
    if (this.y < object.y + 64 && this.y + 64 > object.y) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

FWIW I think you should be consistent with your use of statement brackets because I can see that ending you up in all kinds of trouble.

Comment: You're suggesting code that doesn't work. Please remove the `this.16` from your code one way or another, because your example code keeps the code that's causing errors intact, so it certainly doesn't answer the question of how to make it execute without errors.

Comment: I said in the answer that the OP should fix the problem.

Comment: still, you're not answering the question then, while you're posting this as an answer... It's like saying "let me help you... go fix it yourself."

Comment: It's a _useful_ answer. Holt made the point, I clarified that in my answer.

Comment: it's a useful *comment*, but it's not even *trying* to answer the actual question OP asked.